# Is there any inherent difference between these two python negations

Tags: python, negation

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> 4 not in a
True
>>> not 4 in a
True
```

Is there any foolproof way to remember 1. when to use which and 2. which is more prone to errors?

Comment: I believe the first one is considered to be more "pythonic", because it reads well.

Comment: always use the first one.  they are equivalent, and the second one is a pylint violation.

Comment: related:  https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ed8b0ee1c531/Python/peephole.c#l405

Comment: Also, the second one could be mistaken for `(not x) in y`, whereas it is `not(x in y)`

Comment: Yes @tobias_k I guess this ambiguity prevails but must be situations where it is sufficiently necessary to use the `not 4 in a` version.